# How to get the id of the invoking html input box in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get the 'id' of the html input box in a JavaScript function to set the value to the respective input box which invoked the JavaScript function

```
<html>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./javasc.js'></script>
<input type='text' id='one' onclick='setVal()'/>
<input type='text' id='two' onclick='setVal()'/>
</html>
```

### javasc.js

```
function setVal()
{
$('#one').val("First Message");
$('#two').val("Second Message");              
}
```

I want something like this.

### javasc.js

```
function setVal()
{
id=getElementIdWhichInvokedTheFunction();
$(id).val("Some Message");             
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` references:

```
function setVal(elem) {
    id = elem.id;
    $(id).val("Some Message");                 
}
```

To invoke:

```
setVal(this);
```

---

## Update

If you pass the object, you don't need the ID to manipulate it:

```
function setVal(elem) {
    $(elem).val("Some message");
}
```

You still invoke using `setVal(this);`

#### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uS66K/1/)

Comment: what is the need of passing `this` ?

Comment: He'll need the reference of the object by using it with `onclick`, or am I wrong? Does it work like a `bind` passing caller reference?

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira Your code is fine. But some how it will not work in the last `$(id)....` But no need to double check when we have whole `elem` as a parameter no need to get ID and for that `$(elem).val("Some Messege")`is enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your function like in your post

```
<input type='text' id='one' onclick='setVal()'/>
```

you will need to change it to

```
<input type='text' id='one' onclick='setVal(this);' />
```

and modify the function to accept an argument.

**OR**

http://jsfiddle.net/C9VQC/1/

```
<input type='text' id='one' />
<input type='text' id='two' />

$("input").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this`(current element), which is being clicked and get the id from this element inside `setVal()`, something like

```
function setVal(elem){
    id=elem.id; // id is 'one' if you click on button one
    //do action with fetched id
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $(this).val("Some message");
});
```

Then remove the `onclick` attribute from the HTML. If you have other `input` elements on the page that you do not want affected, use the following:

```
$("#one,#two").click(function(){
    $(this).val("Some message");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass the id while calling the function, and then set the value.

```
.....
<input type='text' id='one' onclick='setVal("one")'/>
.....

function setVal(this)
{
$(this).val("some message");
}
```

Comment: Where you have passed the `id`, and are you really getting the passed element by `this`?